# Requesting info from a device connected to a com port using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm using Windows PowerShell Integrated Scripting Environment (ISE).
What I'm trying to do is get setup information from a solar inverter that is connected via com3,115200,8,and 1 data bits. I bought this inverter and there is no brand name or model #.
So I'm trying to open com port and get any info that I can, to help with setup. I have very little experience writing code.

Comment: Where did you buy the inverter?  Are you able to provide any information about it?

Comment: Bought it from an auction. This is a hole system less li-ion batteries, display and charger. Has everything to connect to the grid. these were made for a pilot program that California electric paid for. they decommissioned them last year.

Comment: Here is the article  http://www.businesswire.com/news/home/20101006005244/en#.UuK5JWco7uo

Answer (score 1):

Originally, I thought this would be a job for WMI, then I discovered this example, which I thought you may be able to modify:

```
[$port = new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM6,115200,None,8,one
$port.Open()
$port.WriteLine( "at+csq" + "`r" )
start-sleep -m 50
$port.ReadExisting()
$port.Close()][1]
```